# Vim Regex : How to search for NOT A AND B

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I am newbie on regex. I am looking to find lines that not include A and include B then mask the B.

My target is credit card numbers in log file that matching line doesn't contain "xxx".

**Credit Card Pattern**
16 digit starts with 3, 4, 5 or 6, separeted with "-", space or nothing and limited with space, ",", "'" or """ like below.

3214745869874125 / 3214 7458 6987 4125 / 3214-7458-6987-4125

4214745869874125 / 4214 7458 6987 4125 / 4214-7458-6987-4125

5214745869874125 / 5214 7458 6987 4125 / 5214-7458-6987-4125

6214745869874125 / 6214 7458 6987 4125 / 6214-7458-6987-4125

3214745869874125 /"3214745869874125"/'3214745869874125'/,3214745869874125,

I write something for finding card numbers and masking number. This works but i need to match with lines that doesn't include "xxx"
This can convert

`%s/\([ ,'"][3456]\d\{3}[- ]\?\d\{2}\)\d\{2}\([- ]\?\)\d\{4}\([- ]\?\d\{4}[ ,'"]\)/\1**\2****\3/gc`

to this

321474******4125 / 3214 74** **** 4125 / 3214-74**-****-4125

421474******4125 / 4214 74** **** 4125 / 4214-74**-****-4125

521474******4125 / 5214 74** **** 4125 / 5214-74**-****-4125

621474******4125 / 6214 74** **** 4125 / 6214-74**-****-4125

321474******4125 /"321474******4125"/'321474******4125'/,321474******4125,

I looked at \& but couldn't make use of it. I tried this,

`%s/\(101011\)\&\([ ,'”][3456]\d\{3}[- ]\?\d\{2}\)\d\{2}\([- ]\?\)\d\{4}\([- ]\?\d\{4}[ ,'”]\)/\1**\2****\3/gc`

this,

`%s/101011\&\([ ,'”][3456]\d\{3}[- ]\?\d\{2}\)\d\{2}\([- ]\?\)\d\{4}\([- ]\?\d\{4}[ ,'”]\)/\1**\2****\3/gc`

and this,

`%s/\(.*101011\)\&\([ ,'"][3456]\d\{3}[- ]\?\d\{2}\)\d\{2}\([- ]\?\)\d\{4}\([- ]\?\d\{4}[ ,'"]\)/\1**\2****\3/gc`

---

**SOLVED**

I solved like this,

`%v/xxx/s/\([ ,’”][3456]\d\{3}[- ]\?\d\{2}\)\d\{2}\([- ]\?\)\d\{4}\([- ]\?\d\{4}[ ,’”]\)/\1**\2****\3/gc`

Comment: can you make a simple example, and tell what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i am looking for

`aaa, "4125 2636 4785 1231"` 
to mask like this 
`aaa, "4125 **** **85 1231"`

this line must not be masked

`xxx, "4125 2636 4785 1231"`

Comment: I think you want to do `:v/xxx/s/<credit card regex>/<replacement>`. But I have no idea what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. You may have already worked on the problem for hours, but you should consider that the people here who is reading your question has no idea what is requirement, what credit card pattern etc.

You should make yourself clear.  Even though you put an example in comment, it is not clear either.  Anyway, for your example, the below line works.

The key is, you could use `\zs \ze` to set the border of your substitution.

```
   %s/\v.*"\d{4}[- ]\zs\d{4}([- ])\d\d\ze\d\d[- ]\d{4}".*/****\1**/
```

This line change:

```
aaa, "4125 2636 4785 1231"
```

into

```
aaa, "4125 **** **85 1231"
```

The separator could be `SPACE or -`

Answer (score 1):

The latest Vim includes the [logipat plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1290). So you can use the command
`:Logipat !"A"&"B"` to search for lines not matching pattern A and matching pattern B